# How to add additional javascript in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have chrome extension which opens camera when i click extension icon. I want that after reload page  show camera again. I use additional javascript to ckeck page shows camera or not. I am interested in how can i send message from this script to content script and how can i add this script. Need to be added to the manifest and how? reload script dont connected to background script maybe we need to add reload.js to manifest file. here is my code

manifest:

```
{
    "name": "Webcam extension",
    "description" : "webcam extension",
    "version": "1.0",

    "options_page": "options.html",

    "icons":{
        "128":"./images/webcam.png",
        "48":"./images/webcam.png",
        "16":"./images/webcam.png"
    },

    "manifest_version": 2,
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "./images/webcam.png"

    },

    "permissions": ["<all_urls>", "activeTab", "tabs", "storage", "http://*/",
      "https://*/",  "contentSettings" ],

    "background": {
        "persistent": false,

        "scripts":["background.js"]

      },

    "content_scripts": [
        {
          "run_at": "document_start",
          "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
          "css":        ["content.css"],
          "js": ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
        }
      ]

}
```

background.js:

```
    chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function (){
     chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
      chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0].id, {ShowCamera:'true'});
       });       
     })
```

reload.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function({ShowCamera}, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (ShowCamera === 'true') {
      const addCamera = 'addCamera';
       chrome.storage.local.set({test: addCamera })

     }
  });
```

```
content.js:

     chrome.storage.local.get(['test'], function(result) {
         console.log(result.test)
        });
```

Comment: 1) reload.js is not needed at all, simply move its onMessage listener into content.js. 2) No need for storage, simply start doing what you want in the listener.

Comment: I need reload because content is not working after page reload

Comment: i need additional javascript to solve this problem

Comment: "content is not working after page reload" - Normally it works so I guess you're doing something wrong. The solution I suggested is correct.

Comment: my camera is working well when i write it in content, but after page reload it does not work

Comment: if you say that reload.js is not necessary, then tell me what is the problem in my code and why it does not work after page reload, what can i do more in content.js

Comment: Where/how do you run reload.js?

Comment: my question was just about it. Is it possible to add it in manifest, or where can i connect it

Comment: I no longer understand what you mean so I can't help, apparently.

Comment: I want that my camera stays opened when i reload page. how can i do it ?  you said that i can do it in content js, please  describe me what did you mean

Comment: I've already described the correct solution. I don't understand what you wrote about reload.js and how it helps you so I can't help, apparently.